# Adobe Illustrator - No fill or stroke, still have a outline

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, stroke, fill

This is perplexing me. All of the shapes I am creating still have a outline around them in white no matter what I do. I can't figure it out.

Has anyone experienced this before?

[image: Appearance Window showing no stoke or fill]

The shape looks like this:

[image: What the rectangle looks like, no fill or stroke]

I apologize if this is something simple. I've never seen this before, any help is appreciated!

**Edit:** sadly, I'm only able to post two images currently.

Comment: Could be a stroke applied to the layer…select the layer in the layers panel (not just all the objects within the layer) and see what the appearance panel says then.

Comment: @NateGreen your comment helped me, why not post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Click on the whole layer (not the sublayer but the main one) and put no stroke and no fill.

Comment: Welcome! Can you add screenshot(s) to visualize what to do to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very late, but I had the same problem.

You need to click on the square box to the left of "Fill" to turn the view appearance on.

[image: Menu View Toggle Box]